# Updating a state hook setter in a functional component's body

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a hard time finding a definitive answer to this and the behavior seems inconsistent in my testing. Am I allowed to set the value of a state (defined using the `useState` hook) directly inside a function's body or do I have to use the `useEffect` hook to do so?

For example:

```
const Test = () => {
  // A context provider which provides the window's scroll position.
  const scrollContext = useContext(ScrollContext);

  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  // If the page has ever been scrolled past 200 pixels 
  // set scrolled to `true`. Is this valid?
  if (!scrolled && scrollContext.scrollY > 200) setScrolled(true);

  return (
     <div>{scrolled.toString()}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is valid!

Comment: It used to be wrong in React with classes, see https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#breaking-changes - Quote: "you should not be calling setState from render."). But, I don't see any mention of this in the documentation for functional components and hooks. I try to set states always within event listeners or inside useEffects callbacks, but haven't found supporting evidence for that other than the one I already linked here in my comment.

Comment: @katamaster818 do you have a source for this comment?